# Html audio unable to set currentTime even inside canplay eventhandler

Tags: javascript, dom-events, html5-audio

I am trying to set the `currentTime` of a audio inside `canplay` event listener but its not working on server but works when directly html file is opened .

```
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio-element");
    var softSlider = document.getElementById('aslider');
    audio.addEventListener('canplay', function () { 
        softSlider.noUiSlider.on('set.one', function (values, handle, unencoded, tap, positions) { 
        
            console.log("triggerd "+handle+" "+values)
            if (handle==0){
                audio.pause();
                startTime=values[handle];
            
                audio.currentTime=startTime;
                // vv.play();
        
            }
            else if(handle==1){
                endTime=values[handle];
                
                    audio.pause();
                    audio.currentTime=startTime;
                
        
            }
            console.log("value "+audio.currentTime);
        
        
        });
    });
```

The event is firing and getting log but every time `currentTime` goes back to  0

```
//Log
audio duration information available
triggerd 0 25.94,211.33
value 0
```

as in the log event fired by a slider with handle 0 and `starttime` should be set to 25.94 but after I set `currentTime` to 25.94 it falls back to 0. I am also using loadedmetadata to check metadata is available or not.

I am using chrome Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit) Running with django templates